# Rearranging Data in CSV by Certain Data in a Column

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with about 30,000 lines of data with 24 columns. The last column is a geographic column and looks something like this:

```
 Ethiopia
 IL
 IL
 TX
 TX
 MD
 NY
 NY
 Ethiopia
 Ethiopia
 Sweden
 CA
 CA
 HI
 Latvia
 OH
```

Right now I only want the entire CSV with all the rows to correspond to the geographic locations of the United States which would be the 2 character state abbreviations (CA, HI, OH, etc.)

Basically I want all the data in the CSV to remove anything non USA related, or even better if possible, to arrange the first X amount of lines by USA based locations and the rest by everything else at the end of the CSV.

Here is my code so far:

```
import csv

ask = "Y"

while ask != "N":
    inputfile = input("Please enter filename: ")
    filename = open(inputfile, "r")

    data = []
    with filename as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            if len(row[24]) == 3:
                data = row[24]
        datalist = row[0:23].join(data)
        output = open("Newly Created Data.csv","w")
        output.write(datalist)
        print ("Done.")

    output.close()

    ask = input("Another file, Y or N? ")
```

It arranges the data in column 24 correctly by only reading the USA locations, but I don't know how to sort the rest of the file and the other 23 columns to match with only USA locations.

I'm using Python 3, thanks.

Comment: So you want to remove all lines whose content doesn't match the any abbreviation such as CA, HI, OH (US states?)

Comment: Correct, or more preferably sort the USA locations at the top of the CSV and the rest of the locations at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a purely standard library solution, maybe something like

```
import csv

with open('location.csv', newline='') as fp_in:
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter=',')
    data = list(reader)

data.sort(key=lambda x: (len(x[-1].strip()) != 2, x[-1].strip()))

with open("locout.csv", "w", newline='') as fp_out:
    writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(data)
```

The sort key function, `lambda x: (len(x[-1].strip()) != 2, x[-1].strip()))`, means that it'll sort the data first by whether or not the last column has two characters or not, putting 2-character locations first, and secondly by the name (effectively alphabetizing them, at least if they all start with a capital letter.)

I'm assuming that the file isn't too large: 30000 lines isn't very many, even with 24 columns, so we might as well work entirely in memory.

(Aside: if you're doing a lot of CSV manipulations, you might be interested in the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library -- it makes a lot of operations much simpler than they'd be otherwise.)

Comment: This worked thanks. Will the sort also work for comparing strings such as x[-1].strip() != "2012"?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
states = set(["AL","AK","AZ","AR","CA","CO","CT","DE","FL","GA","HI","ID","IL","IN","IA","KS","KY","LA","ME","MD","MA","MI","MN","MS","MO","MT","NE","NV","NH","NJ","NM","NY","NC","ND","OH","OK","OR","PA","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VT","VA","WA","WV","WI","WY",])

with open('file.txt') as f, open('ofile.txt','w+') as o:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(o)
    writer.writerows(sorted(reader,key=lambda row: not row[-1] in states))
```

Will sort a file like

```
A,B,C,Ethiopia
A,B,C,IL
A,B,C,IL
A,B,C,TX
A,B,C,TX
A,B,C,MD
A,B,C,NY
A,B,C,NY
A,B,C,Ethiopia
A,B,C,Ethiopia
A,B,C,Sweden
A,B,C,CA
A,B,C,CA
A,B,C,HI
A,B,C,Latvia
A,B,C,OH
```

Into

```
A,B,C,IL

A,B,C,IL

A,B,C,TX

A,B,C,TX

A,B,C,MD

A,B,C,NY

A,B,C,NY

A,B,C,CA

A,B,C,CA

A,B,C,HI

A,B,C,OH

A,B,C,Ethiopia

A,B,C,Ethiopia

A,B,C,Ethiopia

A,B,C,Sweden

A,B,C,Latvia
```

Which when read back like so:

```
with open('ofile.txt') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        print(line)
```

Produces:

```
>>> 
['A', 'B', 'C', 'IL']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'IL']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'TX']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'TX']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'MD']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'NY']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'NY']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'CA']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'CA']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'HI']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'OH']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'Ethiopia']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'Ethiopia']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'Ethiopia']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'Sweden']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'Latvia']
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Hmm, I'm not sure this worked for my file, it ran fine but didn't sort it. Here is the file I am using: http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1369074562